# Account for two levels of robust standard errors in school data

Tags: matching, clustered-standard-errors

I am relatively new to Statistics and R, so please forgive my naive question. I have clustered school data and would like to employ matching followed by a regression. In the paper I read ("Matching Methods for Clustered Observationsl Studies in Education" by Keele et. al) it was recommended to account for both with-in school correlations and pair-wise correlations (from matching) with robust standard errors or random effects.

As I am not familiar with random effects and only know how to use robust standard errors on one level, how would I use robust standard errors for both levels (with-in school correlations and pair-wise correlations) in R?

Comment: Was the matching done prior to sampling, or are you discarding sampled data by incorporating matching?  If the latter please rethink.  Matching is a highly ineffective approach when it involves either (1) any arbitrariness in the choice of matching algorithm or (2) discarding valid observations.  For more see [this](http://hbiostat.org/bbr/md/reg.html#stratification-vs--matching-vs--regression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R this is simple. Using the `sandwich` package, which is the package used for robust standard errors, you can simply run the following:

```r
library(sandwich); library(lmtest)
fit <- lm(Y ~ treat, data = matched_data)
coeftest(fit, vcov. = vcovCL, cluster = ~subclass + school)
```

The assumes `matched_data` contains the results of your matching and has a column called `subclass` containing pair membership (e.g., as the output of a call to `match.data()` after `MatchIt::matchit()`) and `school` the name of the school variable. This performs multi-way clustering, accounting for both types of clustering, which is explained in the vignette for the `sandwich` package.

Comment: Thank you Noah, that was exactly what I was looking for.